# Speed up LINQ query - EF5

Tags: linq, entity-framework, optimization, entity-framework-5

I have the following LINQ query using EF5 and generic repository, unit of work patterns to a SQL Server 2008 db

```
        var countriesArr = GetIdsFromDelimStr(countries);
        var competitionsArr = GetIdsFromDelimStr(competitions);
        var filterTeamName = string.Empty;

        if (teamName != null)
        {
            filterTeamName = teamName.ToUpper();
        }

        using (var unitOfWork = new FootballUnitOfWork(ConnFooty))
        {

            // give us our selection of teams
            var teams =
                (from team in
                     unitOfWork.TeamRepository.Find()
                 where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterTeamName) || team.Name.ToUpper().Contains(filterTeamName)) &&
                        (countriesArr.Contains(team.Venue.Country.Id) || countriesArr.Count() == 0))
                 select new
                            {
                                tId = team.Id
                            }).Distinct();

            // give us our selection of contests
            var conts = (
                            from cont in
                                unitOfWork.ContestRepository.Find(
                                    c =>
                                    ((c.ContestType == ContestType.League && competitionsArr.Count() == 0) ||
                                     (competitionsArr.Contains(c.Competition.Id) && competitionsArr.Count() == 0)))
                            select new
                                       {
                                           contId = cont.Id
                                       }
                        ).Distinct();

            // get selection of home teams based on contest
            var homecomps = (from fixt in unitOfWork.FixtureDetailsRepository.Find()
                             where
                                 teams.Any(t => t.tId == fixt.HomeTeam.Id) &&
                                 conts.Any(c => c.contId == fixt.Contest.Id)
                             select new
                                        {
                                            teamId = fixt.HomeTeam.Id,
                                            teamName = fixt.HomeTeam.Name,
                                            countryId = fixt.HomeTeam.Venue.Country.Id != null ? fixt.HomeTeam.Venue.Country.Id : 0,
                                            countryName = fixt.HomeTeam.Venue.Country.Id != null ? fixt.HomeTeam.Venue.Country.Name : string.Empty,
                                            compId = fixt.Contest.Competition.Id,
                                            compDesc = fixt.Contest.Competition.Description
                                        }).Distinct();

            // get selection of away teams based on contest
            var awaycomps = (from fixt in unitOfWork.FixtureDetailsRepository.Find()
                             where
                                 teams.Any(t => t.tId == fixt.AwayTeam.Id) &&
                                 conts.Any(c => c.contId == fixt.Contest.Id)
                             select new
                             {
                                 teamId = fixt.AwayTeam.Id,
                                 teamName = fixt.AwayTeam.Name,
                                 countryId = fixt.AwayTeam.Venue.Country.Id != null ? fixt.AwayTeam.Venue.Country.Id : 0,
                                 countryName = fixt.AwayTeam.Venue.Country.Id != null ? fixt.AwayTeam.Venue.Country.Name : string.Empty,
                                 compId = fixt.Contest.Competition.Id,
                                 compDesc = fixt.Contest.Competition.Description
                             }).Distinct();

            // ensure that we return the max competition based on id for home teams
            var homemax = (from t in homecomps
                           group t by t.teamId
                               into grp
                               let maxcomp = grp.Max(g => g.compId)
                               from g in grp
                               where g.compId == maxcomp
                               select g).Distinct();

            // ensure that we return the max competition based on id for away teams
            var awaymax = (from t in awaycomps
                           group t by t.teamId
                               into grp
                               let maxcomp = grp.Max(g => g.compId)
                               from g in grp
                               where g.compId == maxcomp
                               select g).Distinct();

            var filteredteams = homemax.Union(awaymax).OrderBy(t => t.teamName).AsQueryable();
```

As you can see we want to return the following format which is passed across to a WebAPI so we cast the results to types we can relate to in the UI.

Essentially what we are trying to do is get the home and away teams from a fixture, these fixtures have a contest which relates to a competition.  We then get the highest competition id from the grouping and then this is returned with that team.  The country is related to the team based on the venue id, when I was originally doing this i had problems figuring out how to do OR joins in linq which is why i split it down to getting home teams and away team and then grouping them based on competition then unioning them together.

An idea of current table size is fixtures has 7840 rows, teams has 8581 rows, contests has 337 rows and competitions has 96 rows.  The table that is likely to increase rapidly is the fixture table as this is related to football.

The output we want to end up with is

Team Id, Team Name, Country Id, Country Name, Competition Id, Competition Name

Using no filtering this query takes on average around 5 secs, just wondering if anybody has any ideas/pointers on how to make it quicker.

thanks in advance Mark

Comment: In my opinion EF is not the right tool for these kind of queries. Probably the resulting sql statement is horrible. I suggest to use a stored procedure and/or a view. Of course you can call it from EF.

Comment: Analyze the Query plan to find out if any indexes are missing

Comment: Does your unit of work pattern support lazy loading? If it doesn't that will increase the speed massively.

Comment: @DavideIcardi no matter what you choose to write a query in, if you do it badly its not going to work well in SQL. The same is true for EF and SPs. You should always check the generated SQL/query plan, if its bad, fix your query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't judge whether it will speed up things, but your `homemax` and `awaymax` queries could be

```
var homemax = from t in homecomps
              group t by t.teamId into grp
              select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.compId).FirstOrDefault();

var awaymax = from t in awaycomps
              group t by t.teamId into grp
              select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.compId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Further, as you are composing one very large query it may perform better when you cut it up in a few smaller queries that fetch intermediary results. Sometimes a few more roundtrips to the database perform better than one very large query for which the database engine can't find a good execution plan.

Another thing is all these `Distinct()`s. Do you always need them? I think you can do without because you are always fetching data from one table without joining a child collection. Removing them may save a bunch.

Yet another optimization could be to remove the `ToUpper`. The comparison is done by the database engine in SQL and chances are that the database has a case-insensitive collation. If so, the comparison is never case sensitive even if you'd want it to be! Constructs like `Name.ToUpper` cancel the use of any index on `Name` (it is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)).

Comment: hi Gert, thanks for the reply.  Turning lazy loading off dropped it down to around 4 secs, taking the distincts off dropped it down to around 3.75 secs.  When i tried to apply your grouping examples it gives a error on the .First() part (query body must end with a select clause or a group clause) and errors on the union clause in the last linq part - type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage.  So not sure whether this has been copied incorrectly.

Comment: I made some modifications and added another thing that came to my mind.

Comment: brilliant, made them amendments and the time is just above 3 secs, thanks for your help.